# Reading and Editing Adobe XMP and IPTC Metadata from DNGs, etc

Tags: python, metadata, photoshop, xmp, dam

I am working on a project that involves analyzing XMP, IPTC metadata values for sets of files in a directory and modifying them under certain conditions. I wanted to get thoughts on what the cleanest way of doing this was outside of writing in C++ to work with the Adobe XMP SDK. I have read about using the Python XMP Toolkit with Exempi, but initially began having issues with the libraries. I am open to solutions like libraries for Java, PHP, JS, Python, but before I put too much effort into it, I wanted to see if anyone knows the best supported and cleanest solution to working with these types of metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to adding an external program, then [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) is the gold standard.  So much so that [IPTC](https://www.iptc.org/) uses it in the example images on their sites and they communicate with the author about upcoming changes.

You can find a wrapper for it in most languages.  For example, [PyExiftool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/).  This is important because you don't want to call exiftool once per file as "the startup time of loading ExifTool is significant" (see [exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3)).

Comment: Thank you! Exiftool looks extremely promising, and should be fine in an external program since I am just building the solution in a docker container. I will definitely check this out.